# How do you find the current postgres virtualtransaction id?

Tags: postgresql

The `pg_locks` postgres table has a `virtualtransaction` column with values like `20/49779`.  How do you determine the current virtual transaction id?

You can get the transaction id from `txid_current()`, but how do you get the virtual transaction id?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

```
SELECT virtualtransaction
    FROM pg_locks
    WHERE transactionid::text = (txid_current() % (2^32)::bigint)::text;
```

The last part looks a bit hairy, but it's necessary because `txid_current` returns an `int` whereas the `transactionid` column has a special `xid` type.

(for more details see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123183/10371)